# How to retrieve Youtube startup delay, rebuffering events from Client-side Chrome browser?

Tags: python, selenium, youtube-api, video-streaming

I am looking for a solution to accurately measure Youtube Startup delay and rebuffering events from the Chrome web browser. I wish to ideally leverage the selenium automation-based python script to repeat the experiment for a large number of YouTube videos to get the measurements. Below is a piece of code I started with, however, it doesn't return any meaningful figures. Must be, I am missing something. Am I on the right track? Any help would be appreciated.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)


driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/<example-video-id>")

sleep(5)

player_status = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('movie_player').getPlayerState()")
```

Comment: What is _`getPlayerState()`_?

Comment: It seems a method with int return as you find here.

[link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: IMO, that's a YouTube API and doesn't have support in Selenium